# autoresizing mask in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my didSelectRowAtIndexPath I have the following:

```
[self.table beginUpdates];
sideSwipeView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height-25, 320, 25)] autorelease];
sideSwipeView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[cell.contentView addSubview:sideSwipeView];
[self.table endUpdates];
```

and in the heightAtRowIndexPath I add the height of the cell if I am adding a UIView.. but however the UIView position is not sticking to the bottom of the cell's, why is this? It's taking the old cell.frame.size.height value, I want to be able it to adjust dynamically if I resize the height of the cell.
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the autoresizing mask set to flexible bottom margin. If you want the view to stick to the bottom, you want a flexible *top* margin instead (or set it to have flexible height).

Comment: thank you! that solved it.. I thought it was the other way around